How to design a data entry form on a wide screen with side navbar?
I'm trying to design a web form for data entry. Problem is, I have a Navbar on the left side, and the form looks like below (very wide, some contents removed for privacy):

What is the best approach to avoid such long inputs without having "too much" whitespace on the sides?

Make it centered and responsive.

Codepen
Edit after the comment
Actually what forces the form to occupy the full width is the Save Changes button in the upper right corner. If you manage to get rid of the location of the button, the form would not need all that space, giving more meaning to a defined logical width.

Real example

Thanks. Then My page will be divided in two sections: Left section where NavBar is shown and right section where above form will be shown centered, right? Do you know any example apps/websites that are using this model?

Answer updated.-
